# How to hide the Windows 10 mouse pointer/cursor?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not looking to hide the mouse pointer inside a game I am currently making, just whenever a statement is true.
Trying to hide the mouse cursor whenever PAYDAY 2 is focused, because I wanted to make a script to fix a bug in the game (Where you would see both game cursor and mouse cursor, and you have to restart the game to fix it)

```py
pycwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.GetWindowText(pycwnd)
if win32gui.GetWindowText(pycwnd) == "PAYDAY 2":
    # hide cursor here
else:
    # show cursor here
```

Comment: what is the framework for the game? pygame, tkinter, something else?

Comment: Nothing, this isn't specifically part of a game I'm making myself, just relying on whether or not the user is currently focused on the video game PAYDAY 2

Comment: does [that](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-hide-the-mouse-cursor-on-the-terminal-screen/) help?

Comment: unfortunately no, this is for the terminal, i'm talking about the mouse cursor you use to click on things normally